# auto Reset simulators before each XCUITest

Tags: ios, automation, xcuitest

I would like to get simulators auto reset before each of my XCUITest. I was thinking the following options:
 1. add [xcrun simctl erase all] command in scheme ==> Select the Product > Scheme > Edit Scheme… menu. Expand the Scheme Test section. Select Pre-actions under the Test section. Click (+) add "New Run Script Action".
 2. delete the app after each test, via the Springboard in the tearDown phase. But this looks to me is over-killed

I'm thinking the 1st one should be an easier one, but it looks like not working for me. Will that reset simulator before each of my test? or it's just one time thing?

Any other better solution here? I'm wondering in Xcode 9, things will be easier now. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can create a service which is running in your Mac machine and you XCUITest runner app can connect and tell the service to uninstall the app and reinstall it using xcode build command.